# AudioBufferSourceNode frequency data at specific time

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to develop an application to retrieve frequency information of an audio file (loaded in through XHR) at a specific time. I can start playback on an AudioBufferSourceNode at a specific time, with immediate playback, and with a duration of zero (e.g., `sourceNode.start(0,time_in_seconds,0)`), but the contents of my AudioBuffer are inconsistent, and apparently tied to the time in which I try and populate it. I also have to add a callback method to sourceNode.onended to make sure I get any data at all.

I am using `AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(buffer)` to populate my array.

How can I retrieve frequency data from an audio file at a specific time, consistently?

Comment: If you just want to get static frequency information at a certain spot in the your audio file, then I would think it would be easier to do an FFT on the slice of the ArrayBuffer at the point of interest. When it comes to playback it will be hard to accurately get frequency data of a specific spot by playing for 0 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, @notthetup. I'll look into this and see what I find.

Comment: @IanHunter Did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: @okram I don't think I ever did. Sorry!